# Java Virtual Machine "Maximum heap size" vs. Generic JVM argument Xmx

Tags: jvm, websphere, heap-memory

I am in WebSphere admin console under:
Application servers > as-name > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine.

There is a field "Maximum heap size".

There is a field carrying "Generic JVM arguments", where I can add the -Xmx argument to define the max heap.

what is the difference between the two options to specify the max heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.  In practice, the "Maximum heap size" field is converted to the appropriate -X argument when the server launcher builds the command to launch the Java executable.  The attribute on the JVM configuration panel is simply a more user-friendly way to specify that value than having to manage your own -X arguments.